custom storage-backend class not working as expected with s3, boto3 and django-storages
I am following this tutorial here from Michael Herman, trying to setup s3 storage for my django project and I am facing some issues right from the start of the tutorial.
First, when I tried running the collectstatic command, I got this error:
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied
I looked up a bit, and apparently you have to set AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None and doing that fixed it.
So now my static files were being uploaded to the s3 bucket when I ran collectstatic. But when I visited the webpages, the static images and stylesheets were not getting fetched as expected.
I tried many different things at this point, but none of them worked. I typed the s3 object url in the browser and this was the error I was getting:
<Error>
    <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
    <Message>Access Denied</Message>
    <RequestId>419CX01JK1CAKYCS<RequestId>
<HostId>rB7y8qLl5a5G0I1LVx2lexUbJpcvnrdKIMZ3AVq69C81B3j4BRWZwLq5THNLINwSv6q5HFSAednN1yq2tRCQ6THuxEn+S/Kj</HostId>
</Error>

Now the next thing I did was to make all the bucket objects as public. The tutorial doesn't do this and I'm not sure if its a bad thing or not? Anyone please point out if it is.
Using this answer, I set the Block all public access setting to off and also added a Bucket policy like below:
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Sid": "PublicRead",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "s3:GetObject",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::MY-BUCKET-NAME/*"
    }
  ]
}

Now my static images and stylesheets were loading perfectly, but the font files (.woff and other static files that should be downloaded) were showing this error in the console:
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://<bucket-name>.s3.amazonaws.com/static/unfold/fonts/inter/Inter-SemiBold.woff2. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 200.
I gave this error to ChatGPT and it asked me to paste this in the bucket's CORS settings:
[
  {
    "AllowedHeaders": [
      "*"
    ],
    "AllowedMethods": [
      "GET",
      "HEAD"
    ],
    "AllowedOrigins": [
      "*"
    ],
    "ExposeHeaders": [],
    "MaxAgeSeconds": 3000
  }
]

Adding this did end up working, and now all my static files were being uploaded and fetched from the s3 bucket as they were supposed to.
After this I followed the rest of the tutorial to set up my media files. I added 3 storage backend classes inheriting from S3Boto3Storage
class StaticStorage(S3Boto3Storage):
    location = 'static'
    default_acl = 'public-read'

class PublicMediaStorage(S3Boto3Storage): 
    location = 'media' 
    default_acl = 'public-read' 
    file_overwrite = False

class PrivateMediaStorage(S3Boto3Storage): 
    location = 'private' 
    default_acl = 'private' 
    file_overwrite = False 
    custom_domain = False

# settings.py is like this

if USE_S3:
    # aws settings
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.getenv('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.getenv('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
    AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.getenv('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')
    AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = os.getenv('AWS_S3_REGION_NAME')
    AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None
    AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = f'{AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME}.s3.amazonaws.com'
    AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {'CacheControl': 'max-age=86400'}
    # s3 static settings
    STATIC_LOCATION = 'public-read'
    STATIC_URL = f'https://{AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN}/{STATIC_LOCATION}/'
    STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'myproject.storage_backends.StaticStorage'
    # s3 public media settings
    PUBLIC_MEDIA_LOCATION = 'media'
    MEDIA_URL = f'https://{AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN}/{PUBLIC_MEDIA_LOCATION}/'
    DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'myproject.storage_backends.PublicMediaStorage'
    # s3 private media settings
    PRIVATE_MEDIA_LOCATION = 'private'
    PRIVATE_FILE_STORAGE = 'myproject.storage_backends.PrivateMediaStorage'
else:
    STATIC_URL = 'static/'
    STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'staticfiles'
    MEDIA_URL = 'media/'
    MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'mediafiles'

Media files are getting uploaded to and served from the bucket now, but there is an issue with the PrivateMediaStorage class. The files uploaded using PublicMediaStorage can be accessed by anyone with the object url as is expected. But for some reason the files uploaded using PrivateMediaStorage are also publicly accessible by their url, and I'm not talking about the signed url having the AWSAccessKeyId, just plain object url of the form: https://<bucket-name>.s3.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com/private/hello.txt
I'm not sure what step went wrong.
